# Why is Excel showing this error when I try to do data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do data validation in excel but it shows this error.
[Here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNssZ.png)

I am trying to add a dropdown of some cells from a different spreadsheet but this error comes up.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems there is a space after sheet name? Do you have space in sheet name?

Comment: Yes I do have a space in the sheet name. The sheet name is 'Dominos Data'

Comment: Can you try `=INDIRECT("'Dominos Data '!$E$4:$E$7")`. I am not sure but space may cause trouble in case of MAC excel. Windows excel is fine.

Comment: If I do this would it work on Windows aswell as Mac?

Comment: Windows excel will work, I am sure.

Comment: And also I tried that thing you sent but it came up with an error 'Alert this source evaluates to an error'